# Error code: AUTO_SCALING_CONFIGURATION Blue/Green Deployment in AWS CodeDeploy. Only when i set dynamic autoscaling policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I have config elastic load balancer, Autoscale and CodeDeploy with Deployment type : Blue/green deployment 
Environment configuration: Automatically copy Auto Scaling group.

[CodeDeploy Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkwZF.png)

It's working fine. but when i set dynamic autoscale policy

it's return error.

Deployment Failed
The deployment failed because a non-empty field was discovered on your Auto Scaling group that Code Deploy does not currently support copying. Unsupported fields: [DescribePoliciesResponse.DescribePoliciesResult.ScalingPolicies.member.Alarms.member.AlarmARN, DescribePoliciesResponse.DescribePoliciesResult.ScalingPolicies.member.StepAdjustments.member.MetricIntervalUpperBound, DescribePoliciesResponse.DescribePoliciesResult.ScalingPolicies.member.StepAdjustments.member.MetricIntervalLowerBound, DescribePoliciesResponse.DescribePoliciesResult.ScalingPolicies.member.StepAdjustments.member.ScalingAdjustment, DescribePoliciesResponse.DescribePoliciesResult.ScalingPolicies.member.Alarms.member.AlarmName] (Error code: AUTO_SCALING_CONFIGURATION)

[CodeDeploy Fail Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqm3Y.png)

Am i missing any config setting?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a different unsupported fields description

Comment: I found my issue to be caused from using an application load balancer instead of a classic.

Answer (score 1):

Code Deploy Blue Green does not support ALB yet. That being said the above error that you are getting is mostly due to a bug on our end which we are already working on. The fix should be out soon.

Comment: Thanks Deblina Gupta.